# Can a SAML assertion be used for API to API authentication without Ui

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, saml, saml-2.0

We have a client exposing the SAML Identity provider for SSO, which as shown in the workflow diagram underneath, needs HTTP Post redirect from the client browser and provides the SAML response which helps in validation and authentication

[image]

I intend to use in a way similar to OAuth2 access token, which can help in authentication without any UI, while the client has the ability to make Http post request, but no Ui based challenge. Client can be similar to a http client postman, which enables the bearer token to access the resource.

Any pointer or article which can help understand the process, pros and cons, whether this is feasible. As of now client is not keen to expose the OAuth2 integration.

Comment: Machine to machine SAML typically uses WS-Trust, not SAML, because of the typical requirement for UX in SAML.  Can your partner expose WS-Trust? If not, then they should expose OAuth.